# Use ExecutorCompletionService to perform concurrent calls to different dependencies

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use the ExecutorCompletionService - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html, to try and perform concurrent calls to two different dependent packages.

The reason I am using ExecutorCompletionService is because I want to compare the results returned by both the dependencies and then emit a metric based on a specific requirement.

My code looks like this:

```
@Builder
@Slf4j
public class TestClass {

    @NonNull private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    @NonNull private final ExecutorCompletionService<ResultStructure1> dependency1Thread = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);
    @NonNull private final ExecutorCompletionService<ResultStructure2> dependency2Thread = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);

    public void myMethod() {

        RequestObject1 firstDependencyRequest = RequestObject1.builder()
                .attribute1("someValue")
                .attribute2("secondValue");

        RequestObject2 secondDepdencyRequest = RequestObject1.builder()
                .attribute1("depdency2Value")
                .attribute2("depdency2Secondvalue");

        dependency1Thread.submit(() -> dependency1Client1.call(firstDependencyRequest));
        dependency2Thread.submit(() -> dependencyClient2.call(secondDepdencyRequest));

        final Future<ResultStructure1> future1 = dependency1Thread.take();
        final Future<ResultStructure2> future2 = dependency2Thread.take();
        try {
            ResultStructure1 = future1.get();
            ResultStructure2 = future2.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("Exception calling dependency", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to be using ExecutorCompletionService for different dependencies? Is there a way to have a single executorService and have both the dependencies be called from that?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the purpose? It literally gives you _nothing_ over `ExecutorService.submit`. `ExecutorCompletionService` is for dumping a **number** of tasks into it and the reacting to them as they complete. If it largely superseded by `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: I am trying to do dual writes and I want to compare the results returned from the two dependencies.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.runAsync(firstDependencyRequest), CompletableFuture.runAsync(firstDependencyRequest))` will give you a `CompletableFuture` that complete when both tasks complete.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Apologies if my question sounds stupid, would the CompletableFuture also provide me the results from the API calls to the dependencies?

Comment: Nvm, found the answer

Comment: It would be up to you to code that - some [reading](http://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture) may be required. But my point still stands - your usage of `ExecutorCompletionService` is wrong because it does nothing. [`ExecutorService.submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) already returns a `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to be using ExecutorCompletionService for
>   different dependencies?

Unfortunately, no. You'd typically use it to execute tasks returning similar type of results while you wait for their execution and their results to be available. Internally it uses a `BlockingQueue` where it adds the `Future`s as the tasks complete, which is then returned by its blocking `take` method.

So, if you do want to use an `ExecutorCompletionService`, you'd have to come up with a base/common type for `ResultStructure1` and `ResultStructure2` (i.e., `ResultStructure`), and declare a completion service like below -

```
private final ExecutorCompletionService<ResultStructure> completionService = 
    new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool)
```

and then -

```
completionService.submit(() -> dependency1Client1.call(firstDependencyRequest));
completionService.submit(() -> dependencyClient2.call(secondDepdencyRequest));
```

You can then wait for their results to be available using the blocking `take` method -

```
Future<ResultStructure> result1 = completionService.take();
Future<ResultStructure> result2 = completionService.take();
```

Please note that at this point, we have no way of finding out which `Future` represents which concrete result type. So you have no way of comparing the results.

My recommendation would be to simply use ExecutorService directly.